# Background service mobilefirst 7.1 is not working

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I downloaded the sample Location services project from https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/location-services-hybrid-applications/. From the sample I kept posChange trigger policy and i deleted the other two. And I am getting the location when app is opened. But not in the app is closed. Below the snippet

```
function getFirstPositionAndTrack() {
    var geoPolicy = WL.Device.Geo.Profiles.RoughTracking();
    geoPolicy.timeout = 60000; 
    geoPolicy.maximumAge = 10000; 
    geoPolicy.minChangeDistance = 3;

    WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(
        function(pos) {
                var triggers = {
                Geo: {
                    posChange: { // display all movement
                        type: "PositionChange",
                        minChangeDistance: 5,
                        callback: function(deviceContext) {
                                WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'deviceLocation'}, true);
                                }
                    },
                }   
            };

            WL.Device.startAcquisition({ Geo: geoPolicy }, triggers, { Geo: alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr } );
        },
        function(geoErr) {
            console.log(geoErr);
            // try again:
            getFirstPositionAndTrack();
        },
        geoPolicy
    ); 
}
```

And in adapter to check background

```
WL.Server.setEventHandlers([
    WL.Server.createEventHandler({ event: 'deviceLocation'}, deviceEvent)
]);
```

Procedure

```
function deviceEvent(event) {
    WL.Logger.error(JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

And in onconnectSuccess I am calling the function and setting the keepAlive Property

```
getFirstPositionAndTrack() 
WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true);
```

And is there any other way to debug when app is in background or closed?

Comment: Just FYI: this is a discontinued feature. i.e. in v8.0 it's gone. My suggestion to you is to use Cordova's Location API instead in MobileFirst Hybrid app.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. For now, i am working with 7.1.0 will MFP API support our requirement capturing the location on background

Comment: Try using "WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true, options)" and put some logger lines in the callback. You will know if the API is firing.
Also: For Android devices and native applications, you should access the location APIs through a service. For more information about Android services, see the "Services" section on the Android development site at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html.

Comment: Tried with options but no response and no logs. In the sample project still we need to define the  services?